# bryntum scheduler showCheckAll doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, bryntum-scheduler

the code of the config :

```
columns: [
        {
            type  : 'check',
            //text: "selectionner tout",
            showCheckAll : true,
            listeners:{
                toggle:(source,record,checked)=>{console.log('################'+checked);},
                toggleAll:(source,record,checked)=>{console.log('################'+checked);}
            }
        },
.... }
```

the checkbox in the header does not appear !!
I tried working with selectionMode but it also doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the full code or the GitHub repo?

Answer (score 1):

Testing your code on bryntum editor here: https://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler/basic/ it works fine:
[image: All columns checkbox]

Please check if all bryntum files are included on your project, including css files.

Tested also on this example on local env and it works fine: https://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler/vue/javascript/advanced/dist/index.html

Here are the steps to how you have to install the Bryntum Scheduler on your project: https://www.bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/#guides/readme.md

And here you can see the steps to integrate with vue: https://www.bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/#guides/integration/vue.md

On Bryntum forum your can find more content about: https://www.bryntum.com/forum

Comment: maybe something is missing i can't find out what it is because it's a big project I'm working ... well i tried to add checkboxes using headerrender and render so all checkboxes are added manually ... I'm trying to add events using jquery but at every scroll the option render is called again so i lose events !! ... any idea about this problem ?

Comment: I would recommend you open a question on Bryntum  forum and would need a test case to help, really.